# Loopback: Validating the user in a remote method

Tags: authentication, loopbackjs

I have create a task model, which shall optionally store information about its owner, to make it a private Task. Private Task shall only be seen by there owner.

I now would like to check for this property and compare it to a current authenticated user in custom remote methods i write.

Is this possible in Loopback?

Comment: There are ACL checks for this. Check https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Controlling-data-access.html for ACL docs. You can use $owner or create custom roles for this.

Answer (score 0):

Loopback has very good `ACL` features defined for this kind of permissions check.

Let's suppose your model name is `PrivateTask` which stores information about its owner, now to add permission so that only owner can see this is by setting ACL like this.

> models/private-task.json

```
{
   ...
   ...
   "acl":[
       {
          "accessType": "*",
          "principalType": "ROLE",
          "principalId": "$everyone",
          "permission": "DENY"
       },
       {
         "accessType": "*",
         "principalType": "ROLE",
         "principalId": "$owner",
         "permission": "ALLOW"
       }
   ]
```

Here, First one with principal id `$everyone` with permission `DENY`  will deny `all kinds of user` who wants to access this `model`. Second permission with role `$owner` will allow `only owner` to have access to its data.

For more info refer to https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Controlling-data-access.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the [current context](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-current-context.html).

On your remote method definition (in the model.js file) you can add an extra `options` parameter. See this example from the link above:

```
// common/models/my-model.js
module.exports = function(MyModel) {
  MyModel.log = function(messageId, options) {
    const Message = this.app.models.Message;
    // IMPORTANT: forward the options arg
    return Message.findById(messageId, null, options)
      .then(msg => {
        const token = options && options.accessToken;
        const userId = token && token.userId;
        const user = userId ? 'user#' + userId : '<anonymous>';
        console.log('(%s) %s', user, msg.text));
      });
  };
};
```

Then you have to specify that the model accepts the `options` parameter on metadata.

```
// common/models/my-model.json
{
  "name": "MyModel",
  // ...
  "methods": {
    "log": {
      "accepts": [
        {"arg": "messageId", "type": "number", "required": true},
        {"arg": "options", "type": "object", "http": "optionsFromRequest"}
      ],
      "http": {"verb": "POST", "path": "/log/:messageId"}
    }
  }
}
```

The user id is available on `options.token.userId`.